# In CSS, how can I select many nested elements more efficiently?

Tags: css

Look at this CSS file:

```
#footer {...}

#footer a {...}

#footer .b {...}

...
```

I only want to write CSS specific to `#footer`, is there a way to only write `#footer` once?

I mean, does CSS have syntax like this:

```
#footer {
    ...
    a {...}
    .b {...}
    ...
}
```

Comment: see here http://lesscss.org/

Comment: you can do the same in HTML code though. by using multiple html classes.

Comment: [Less CSS](http://lesscss.org/) a best way..

Comment: Or use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: To select all the elements insinde `#footer`, you can use `#footer *`.

Answer (score 3):

see the http://lesscss.org/ site and scroll up to Nested Rules section,
also check it below is example. hope this will help you.

```
// LESS


#header {
  h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  p { font-size: 12px;
    a { text-decoration: none;
      &:hover { border-width: 1px }
    }
  }
}

/* Compiled CSS */

#header h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#header p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#header p a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#header p a:hover {
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

Thanks
Jeremy Voges

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sass (http://sass-lang.com/), too.

There it is possible to write:

```
#footer{
  font-size: 12px;
  p{
    padding: 5px;
  }
  .class{
    margin: 10px 5px;
  }
}
```

So can use the Nesting Feature. But it also supports Variables and a kind of Functions, called Mixins.

A nice Tool when using Sass is Compass (http://compass-style.org/).